# DNN error while adding DNN module on the page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am getting dotnet nuke error whenver i try to add a module on my page. It works well on my local system but gives me dotnet nuke error on the server. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running any custom URL providers, such as Ifinity's URLMaster? If so, be sure to upgrade to the latest release.

If not, what specifically is the error you are receiving?

Comment: DotNetNuke Error

An Unexpected Error has occurred. Support has been notified and the problem will be resolved at the earliest. This is the error i get...and i am redirected to error page

Comment: I would recommend checking out the details in your Event Viewer (eventlog table) to see if there is a more descriptive error

Answer (score 0):

Also check your \Portals_default\Logs\ folder for any logs that might give you a clue about the error